# AS3/AIR: If phone use portrait, if tablet use landscape?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, air, landscape, portrait

Ok, I've written myself a simple DeviceCapabilites class to be able to check if the device is a phone or tablet etc.

But I need to be able to say that if the user is on a phone, it should be in portrait mode, and if on tablet I only wanna use landscape mode... Any ideas?

EDIT: To make it clear, I want to lock the orientation to portrait mode on phones and then use landscape on tablets.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
stage.autoOrients = false;

if(YourDeviceCapsClass.isTablet)
    stage.setOrientation(StageOrientation.ROTATED_LEFT);
else
    stage.setOrientation(StageOrientation.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: This won't help them. `StageOrientation.DEFAULT` is related to the default for the device. This is generally fine for phones, since almost all phones should be portrait by default, some tablets are actually landscape by default (the Asus Transformer Prime is one, I believe).

Comment: `stage.deviceOrientation` might help?

Comment: No, `deviceOrientation` (and `orientation`) appear to report the exact same info and rely on the same StageOrientation constants. You still need the extra logic from my answer to determine if default is landscape or portrait.

Comment: Hi, How could you know it is a tablet or phone. seems I cannot find some class names YourDeviceCapsClass. Do you have some detail statements?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to combine the `setOrientation()` method mentions by Barış Uşaklı with some more logic, I am afraid. As I mentioned in my comment to him, `StageOrientation.DEFAULT` refers to the default orientation of the device, but you don't know if that is landscape or portrait.

Fortunately, there is a simple way to figure that out. You simply see if the device is in default/upside down orientation and check that against the width/height.

```
var defaultPositionIsLandscape:Boolean = false;
if ( stage.orientation == StageOrientation.DEFAULT || stage.orientation == StageOrientation.UPSIDE_DOWN ) {
    defaultPositionIsLandscape = stage.stageWidth > stage.stageHeight;
}
else {
    defaultPositionIsLandscape = stage.stageWidth < stage.stageHeight;
}

if ( isTablet ) {
    if ( defaultPositionIsLandscape ) {
        stage.setOrientation( StageOrientation.DEFAULT );
    }
    else {
        stage.setOrientation( StageOrientation.ROTATED_LEFT );
    }
}
```

The logic is a little messy so you could probably clean it up a bit, but that is the general gist of what has to happen. I personally would make the top part a static, read-only getter in your DeviceCapabilities class for ease of access. You'll also want to expand it to avoid rotating if it is in `StageOrientation.UPSIDE_DOWN` (since that is technically the correct orientation that you want, just upside down)

Comment: Thanks, gonna try to check that out once I'm home.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have an answer but I'd like to save someone else some time. When testing on an ipad, the above code posted by Josh will always result in "defaultPositionIsLandscape" to be false :(